# How can I split seeds.rb to populated different data in development vs. production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, configuration

It looks like I could do this by specifying a constant in the environment files, but is the a more conventional way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need use the `Rails.env` to know which environnement you are and switch data.